# Trying to understanding OSGi resolution errors

Tags: maven, osgi

I'm fairly new to OSGi and I've run into what has to be a very simple, beginner's error.

When I added a BundleActivator to my Bundle, I get the following resolution error:

```
[INFO] Building jar: C:\projects\osgi.enroute-master\projects\testproject\app\target\app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- bnd-indexer-maven-plugin:4.0.0:index (index) @ app ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- bnd-indexer-maven-plugin:4.0.0:index (test-index) @ app ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- bnd-export-maven-plugin:4.0.0:export (default) @ app ---
[ERROR] Resolution failed. Capabilities satisfying the following requirements could not be found:
    [<<INITIAL>>]
      ? osgi.identity: (osgi.identity=org.foo.examples.service.impl)
          ? [org.foo.examples.service.impl version=0.0.1.201806070724]
              ? osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(&(version>=1.9.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
                  ? [org.osgi.framework version=1.9.0.201802012106]
                      ? osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.dto)(&(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
The following requirements are optional:
    [org.apache.felix.scr version=2.1.0]
      ? osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.cm)(&(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
      ? osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.service.command)(&(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
      ? osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.shell)(&(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=1.1.0))))
      ? osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(&(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
      ? osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.metatype)(&(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
```

I'm using the [OSGi enRoute example on GitHub](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute/), which uses maven plugins and custom archetypes to setup the project and different kinds of bundles. It also uses the Bndtools which - as far as I understand - is supposed to automatically resolve exactly these kinds of bundle dependencies. I cannot rule out that underneath the OSGi dependency issue is a Maven dependency as well.

Is there any documentation on how to parse and understand this types of errors?

I know this question is vague, I currently lack the understanding to even precisely formulate the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For resolution errors you first look into the innermost resolution that fails. In your case it is:

```
osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.dto)(&(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
```

This can be translated you are missing a bundle that provides an export of the package "org.osgi.dto" with a version of [1.1.0,2.0.0). This package is provided by

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.dto
```

So you could try to install this bundle.

Comment: Accepting your answer. The root cause of the resolution problems was that Apache Felix doesn't yet implement OSGi framework v1.9. We adapted our main pom.xml to configure Bndtools accordingly and it works now.

Comment: I also suspected it might be related with the status of the R7 spec implementation at felix .. but I don`t know how to fix this in bndtools. What did you do to fix the issue? Did you tell bndtools to use the older spec version?

Comment: Exactly, we are using v1.8 instead of the default (v1.9)